# Changing vanity URL on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, url

As you may know, Facebook allows users to choose a "vanity URL," allowing easy linking to one's profile. However, once set, this URL cannot be changed and this was done for security reasons, understandably.

I have a friend whose now ex-partner set the URL to be "herfirstname.hislastname" without her permission. She tried to change it after this, but to no avail.

Has anyone successfully contacted Facebook and got them to either disable the name and revert back to an ID or change the name to another?

Comment: Has she actually tried contacting Facebook yet?

Comment: She's been waiting more than a week for a reply.

Comment: What form did she use to contact?

Comment: Is there any progress on this?

Comment: I was told that it's Facebook policy to not allow the changing of URLs after they have been changed. I was told that she should delete and recreate her account. Very inconvenient.

Comment: Could you post this as an answer? There is not much if any we can do assist you further without violating Facebook policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told that it's Facebook policy to not allow the changing of URLs after they have been changed. I was told that she should delete and recreate her account.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct process of doing this but there is a little hacky method to do this

http://opendummies.blogspot.in/2014/02/change-your-facebook-username.html

Comment: Please provide more than just a link. Explain what the method actually is.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have explained steps clearly in my blog you can go through still u didnot understand i will help in doing it :)

Comment: These steps clearly don't work.