# URL of a deleted page is not available

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a created a page that I had given the wrong URL to, Facebook said I could not change this URL, and so I created a new page with the correct one. I have since discovered that you *can* change the URL of a page (it requires a certain number of likes) so I deleted the new page and tried to change the old one to the correct URL.

This gives me an error saying the URL is not available, but going to it returns 'a page does not exist' error. Will this URL ever become free or have I locked the URL forever?

Comment: Did you get your preferred URL? If so, how long did you wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the vanity URL. If so, then the username *should* be freed eventually. Deleting a profile seems to free the username so I assume the same is true for pages.

Some pages that have brands that are trademarked for example, may not have this option.

Comment: Do you know how long it takes to become free again?

Comment: @RonanForman no idea, this user waited about two weeks http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25168/reusing-freed-facebook-personal-profile-url-on-another-account-you-own-that-is

Answer (score 0):

Any disabled profile/page username will be freed after 1 yr to 2 yrs. or 6-9 months, depending when Facebook release the disabled names (URL NAME) out.

Comment: Do you have a source to back this up?